# Creating DLL with .DEF to Define function names

Tags: c++, cmd

I am trying to create a DLL and define the function names with a .def file, but it doesn't seem to be working. My header file for me DLL is:

```
 #ifdef ColorDLL_EXPORTS
 #define ColorDLL_API
 #endif

 int ColorSelect(int i);
```

Cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ColorDLL.h"
#using <ColorDiologeClass.dll>

int ColorSelect(int i){
    ColorDiologeClass::Class1::ColorReturn(1);
    return 1;
}
```

I added a ColorDLL.def by right clicking in the Solution Explorer and added a .DEF file the file looks like this:

```
LIBRARY "ColorDLL"

EXPORTS
    ColorSelect
```

When I use Dumpbin /Exports the result for the names is

```
name 
ColorSelect = ?ColorSelect@@YAHH@Z (int __cdec1 ColorSelect(int))
```

I have seen it where the name will look like this

```
name 
ColorSelect
```

How do I get rid of the = part?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `__declspec(dllexport)`, the mangled name will be emitted just as you see. You don't need the .DEF file at all. Remove the first and use only the def file for different outcome.

Note that you have export on both branches of #if.

Comment: So I took you the `__declspec(dllexport)` and I am still having the same issue. How do I get rid of `= ?ColorSelect@@YAHH@Z (int __cdec1 ColorSelect(int))`. Or even better what is that equals part?

Comment: Internally your function name is mangled to that ?-starting thing. With = it indicates alternative names for the same ordinal. Are you sure you rebuilt without declspec?   Btw why you want to hassle with .DEF that way? It only hinders usability.

Comment: Okay so the = just means there is an alternative name for it? Yes I rebuilt it and it without the `__declspec(dllexport)` and I had the same result when using dumpbin. I am trying to use this with JMP and it requires me to give the exact function name inside the DLL, so I had to create a .DEF to define the function names since C++ decorates the names.

Comment: The common way is to make the exported functions `extern "C"`. Then it will still be mangled but in a friendly form, yours like `_ColorSelect@4`. And that string is used for GetProcAddress. It's easy to add _ in front and number of param bytes. With DEF file you can add the simplest name too, and ignore the other form also sitting there.